# Javascript two window.onlick functions clashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a couple of drop down boxes with the below scripts, everything works except for clicking outside of the window, which will only work on the last button, I know there is a way to seperate the window.onclick functions but I'm not sure how, have tried a few things but can't find much information on this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction20() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown20").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event20) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn20')) {

    var dropdowns20 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content20");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns20.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown20 = dropdowns20[i];
      if (openDropdown20.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown20.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction21() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown21").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event21) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn21')) {

    var dropdowns21 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content21");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns21.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown21 = dropdowns21[i];
      if (openDropdown21.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown21.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

the one on the right will close when clicking outside the button and dropdown but the one on the left will not.. https://jsfiddle.net/c94gLhqm/

Comment: Is this not a candidate for the blur event? [MDN blur(event)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)

Comment: I had a look there and don't think this is relevant to my problem, please see this JSFiddle, the one on the right will close when clicking outside the button and dropdown but the one on the left will not.. https://jsfiddle.net/c94gLhqm/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rianodwyer/srngnr5f/ Seems to function ok

Comment: Only if you click the actual button itself but not outside of the button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rianodwyer/srngnr5f/1/ Sorry, not sure I had it saved. It's working for me in Chrome. Opens when I click on button, closes when I click anywhere else

Comment: Ah I see thank you kind stranger

Comment: Just one problem, now the links in the dropdown are unclickable and simply just hide the dropdown again without following the link

Comment: means you need to expand upon `if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn21')) {` to also not target descendants of said el. but at this point we're expanding past the scope of the question you asked.

Comment: Please elaborate, I cannot seem to get it to work at all, I have window.onclick = function(event) and window.onblur = function(event2) but that didn'tm work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the comments chat above. Adding here for clarity. Introduced onblur in the HTML

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #85c445;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 170px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 6
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #85c445;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 170px;
}

.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 6
}

.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button  onblur="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Example</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="">3</a>
<a href="">4</a>
<a href="">5</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown2">
<button onblur="myFunction2()" onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">Example</button>
<div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
<a href="">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="">3</a>
<a href="">4</a>
<a href="">5</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just one problem, now the links in the dropdown are unclickable and simply just hide the dropdown again without following the link

Answer (score 0):

I think change your once window onclick method

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction20() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown20").classList.toggle("show");
}

/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction21() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown21").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event20) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn20')) {

    var dropdowns20 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content20");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns20.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown20 = dropdowns20[i];
      if (openDropdown20.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown20.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  } else if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn21')) {

    var dropdowns21 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content21");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns21.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown21 = dropdowns21[i];
      if (openDropdown21.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown21.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I changed it to this, none of the dropdowns would disappear by clicking outside of the window/button